# Change CurrentDate time zone

Tags: php

I just online my website and uploaded it to GoDaddy server and now facing timezone problem. In my most of the SQL queries i have used **CurrentDate** function which is bringing the server time and i don't want it. I have a second option which is something like this, (to correctly insert date according to my time zone. it fine **but**

```
 date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi");
echo date('Y-m-d')
```

I don't want to change it in this fashion because it require significant change. 
Can i change currentDate function time to Asia/Karachi directly. Remember I tried to change timezone in php.ini but it wont affect

Comment: No, the currentDate function gets the system value. You cannot change it like that!

Comment: Read this article may be it can help you http://bestwebhosting.org/blog/setting-the-correct-timezone-for-your-web-host

Comment: If you make changes in ini then you need to restart server and php services

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to this

1) Set the default timezone in the php.ini file. This would add the same as default globally for all the sites hosted in the environment.

```
date.timezone = Asia/Karachi
```

2) Add the same to the .htaccess file. This would set the timezone for the particular instance in which the htaccess is included.

```
php_value date.timezone 'Asia/Karachi'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is change ini settings internally. put the following code in your index file at the top:

```
ini_set( 'date.timezone', 'Asia/Karachi' );
```